# Oracle View Object Type Column

Tags: oracle, object, types, view, user-defined-types

Object type

```
create or replace TYPE "TYPE_FE_FEE_DETAIL" AS OBJECT
(
  FE_AMOUNT VARCHAR2(25),
  CURR_ID VARCHAR2(5),
  PROFILE_TYPE VARCHAR2(1),
  ISO_CODE VARCHAR2(25)
);

create or replace TYPE "TYPE_TB_FE_FEE_DETAIL" AS TABLE OF type_fe_fee_detail;
```

We have a view with two columns where the second column is of OBJECT TYPE and has data like

```
EPAYPROD_M3.TYPE_TB_FE_FEE_DETAIL(EPAYPROD_M3.TYPE_FE_FEE_DETAIL('10', '1', '1', '818'))
```

I need to insert these four values into a table which has four separate  columns. I am having in trouble doing so.

Comment: are you getting an error ? if so, which one ?

Answer (score 3):

`TYPE_TB_FE_FEE_DETAIL` is a nested table. To get the attribute values, unnest it.

You can do this with the table operator:

```
create or replace TYPE "TYPE_FE_FEE_DETAIL" AS OBJECT
(
  FE_AMOUNT VARCHAR2(25),
  CURR_ID VARCHAR2(5),
  PROFILE_TYPE VARCHAR2(1),
  ISO_CODE VARCHAR2(25)
);
/

create or replace TYPE "TYPE_TB_FE_FEE_DETAIL" AS TABLE OF type_fe_fee_detail;
/
  
with rws as (
  select type_tb_fe_fee_detail(type_fe_fee_detail('10', '1', '1', '818')) obj
  from   dual
)
  select t.*
  from   rws r, table ( r.obj ) t;
  
FE_AMOUNT   CURR_ID   PROFILE_TYPE   ISO_CODE   
10          1         1              818
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. But I have table with multiple rows i have put sample values for reference. How to achieve this using column_name instead of field values

Comment: @Jey - You should post sufficient sample data to **completely** explain your situation, plus desired output derived from that sample. If you can't figure out how to solve the problem from what Chris has given you here you need to **edit your question** to explain what still puzzles you.